# Java, privileged applets, self-sign in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, applet, sign

I would like to run applets without the security restrictions imposed on sandbox. The applet should be able to access client resources such as the local filesystem (upload a file from the local PC).

The source code is written in NetBeans, which supports the applet self-sign. Following the solution in question

[How to self-sign an applet with NetBeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21238954/how-to-self-sign-an-applet-with-netbeans)

and using

```
Project Properties/WebStart/Customize/
```

these options are set:

```
Signing = self-sign by a generated key,
Mixed code = Enable software protection.
```

Unfortunately, the  following error occurs:

```
AccessControlException: access denied, java.io.permition "test.jpg" read
```

Did I do something wrong or self-signed applets can run only in the sandbox? Is there any way to solve the problem using NetBeans?

Sorry for my beginner-question, but my native language is C/C++. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just a friendly reminder that applets are a dead technology that shouldn't be used for anything anymore.

Comment: *"I would like to run applets.."* ..why? If it's something just for you, create a normal desktop app. and use it. If it's for other people, then obtain a proper certificate and sign it as you would with the self-signed applet. But forget the applet, make it a desktop app. & and deploy it from a link using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info), Seriously, applets are dead. See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and ..

Comment: .. [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).